# mount cifs through fstab non readable/writable

Tags: linux, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have FreeNAS server and domain-controller with Windows Server 2008.
I use OpenSuse 11.4 and my Windows account have full access to FreeNAS CIFS share.
I can connect through any filemanager with smb protocol support using `smb://windows_user@freenas/share` and I can read and write to any folder.

Now I'm trying to setup mount.cifs. Here is my string in `/etc/fstab`:

`//freenas/share /mnt/Data cifs username=windows_user,password=windows_password,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0`
(where 1000 is my default linux user ID and 100 is 'users' group ID).

After `mount -a` I see folders from FreeNAS share but I can read/write them only as root user (not default user with ID = 1000).

Also `ls -o` says that folder's owner is 1000 but no read/write access.

I tried options like 'file_mode=0777' or 'dir_mode' or force uid or add user 1000 to root group - none of this worked.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by putting a line in fstab:

```
//192.168.1.33/Public /mnt/nasPublic cifs       username=username,password=password,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

then

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried all of this options (excluding iocharset) but maybe in wrong combination or not all of them together. Now it works!

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me with rw,file_mode,dir_mode (didn't need nounix and iocharset).

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm, do you really want perm 777 on dir and files? You can specify your file and dir mode adn the uid and gid. To allow non-root mounting, try the "user" or "users" option for the mount (see man mount.cifs)

e.g.

```
//myNAS/nasmedia /media/nasmedia cifs noauto,users,_netdev,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1002,file_mode=0774,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but permissions restriction not necessary in my case. All other users connecting to this server via SMB from Windows, only I have Linux :)

Comment: file_mode=0664 would be better